# Jmeter-- Changing data in Grid

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter, jmeter-4.0, post-processor

I have a data grid , i have to update 1 column(MV14 refer image attached) from 6 rows (eg: if value is 0 --replace with -2 )if the count of the data in grid is above 6 and then go to next requests.If the count is less than 6 I want to pick random digit from 1 to 5 and update random no of columns from 1 to 5 .
In this case if i take 2 if controllers , there will be 2 copies of the next requests in both if controllers. What can be done to remove the duplication in Jmeter?[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/selection-statements-in-jmeter-made-easy) instead of 2 If Controllers
2. You can use [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#test_fragments) to keep your HTTP Request sampler in order to avoid copying and pasting the request itself- this way your test will be easier to maintain as in case of changes you will need to perform them in one place only.